# Plugin bypassed when Entity queried from console application

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

My plugin encrypts/decrypts a field. Works on the field within a CRM form.

From my console application, a retrieve bypasses my plugin, e.g., it retrieves the encrypted value directly from the database without running the plugin. When debugging, breakpoints in the plugin are hit when the field is accessed from a form , but they are not hit when accessed from my console program.

I'm surprised that my plugin isn't invoked from a program. It bypasses my business rules.

Here is how I'm accessing the entity and the field from a program:

```
    private static OrganizationServiceProxy service = null;
    private static OrganizationServiceContext orgSvcContext = null;
    public static void RetrieveSSNs()
    {
        var query = orgSvcContext.CreateQuery("bpa_consumer");
        foreach (Entity consumer in query)
        {
            if (consumer.Attributes.Contains("bpa_ssn"))
            {
                string ssn = consumer["bpa_ssn"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Consumer \"{0}\" has SSN {1}", consumer.Attributes["bpa_name"], ssn));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Consumer \"{0}\" doesn't have a SSN", consumer.Attributes["bpa_name"]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you have the plugin registered on the Retrieve method?  If so, add another identical registration on the RetrieveMultiple.  This should get your plugin to execute on your foreach.  I should warn you that this is an extremely dangerous thing to do from a performance standpoint though...

Comment: I can see why it could degrade performance. But suppose that you wish to run applications against CRM and you want your applications to enforce business rules which are encapsulated in your plugins. Is there a better way to handle this? For instance, could you somehow enable a RetrieveMultiple step for a plugin from within an application so that RetrieveMultiple is only enabled for the duration of your application?

Comment: @LarryMale That would be a possibility,  You'd have to look at the code for the plugin registration tool to see what it's doing...  In the situation you describe in your comment, I would abstract the logic in your plugin, into a business layer class that you could reference in both places.  That way the plugin will only have to be registered on the retrieve, but in your app, you could loop through the result set, applying the same logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance my recommendation is to put the encrypted data into a separate entity with a lookup back. Using this method CRM only has to execute the Retrieve/RetrieveMultiple plug-in when a user needs to access the encrypted data, not every time a user accesses the primary record. This will also make it easier to secure the encrypted data.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the you must register your plugin for the event RetrieveMultiple when you query for a collection of Entities.

Comment: I know you're new to Stack Overflow, but here's a tip, don't answer your own question with an answer that has already been given 20 hours earlier.  You should mark the first answer as the answer, and delete yours.